Is It Possible To Removed Claimed Content via YouTube API
When you upload a YouTube video with copyrighted material, you can go in and select one of a few options regarding how you want to handle it (cut segment entirely, dispute the copyright claim, etc.) Is it possible to do this through the API?
I searched https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3 for "Claimed Content" and didn't find anything relevant.

The Youtube data api predates things like "Claimed Content"  They have not updated the API in a long time.
This is something you will need to do though youtube studio.
